# Backbone.Marionette Layout: Regions within Regions

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I've got a quite complex (?) Layout in Backbone.Marionette where some of the Regions are placed within a MainRegion. All of this is part of CollectionView, so it's not possible to adress this Layout directly throu a var:

[image: Regions]
Showing the Views in the right order works fine. But if the MainRegion is re-rendered the inner regions are gone, of cause.

How would you structure those views? 
Is there a way to tell a view in which Region/Layout it is rendered to show the sub-regions after the view was rendered?

I hope i was able to explain my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a Marionette.Layout extends from Marionette.ItemView - so the data from a model can be accessed directly, while the lists are simple Regions. Derick, you are awesome!